# Browsershot won't save or write my pdf -> For some reason Chrome did not write

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, laravel-5, browsershot

Looking for brilliant mind to help me fix my problem. I have inherited a Laravel v5.3 project, and the project should be able to pass CV's from html to .pdf. They have been using spatie/browsershot for that task. But for some reason the package won't write the damn file.
I have been looking at the html passed to the function, and it all checks out. So I went to the guide on Github and put this line of code into the codefile as the only one left in the function.

```
Browsershot::html('<h1>Hello world!!</h1>')->save('example.pdf');
```

No matter what I do, I get this error message:

```
 Spatie \ Browsershot \ Exceptions \ CouldNotTakeBrowsershot
For some reason Chrome did not write a file at `example.pdf`.
```

I have also tried giving an absolute path for Browsershot to save the file at. But no matter. I have looked up many different guides the past two weeks, but nothing seems to work atm. Puppeteer is also installed locally.

I'm running a Windows 10 machine btw, with latest updates, if that matters.

Comment: Did you try with other browser ? Maybe you have to allow your browser to download some files or something like that. Try firefox, IE, any other you have available.

Comment: Just tried it with the brwosers at my disposal. No luck i'm afraid. Thanks for the fresh idea though ;)

Comment: You will have to browse to the vendor file and `dd($targetPath)`, see this [source file](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot/blob/94815d30e61dfe0f833fe705c82f6c27b484041f/src/Browsershot.php#L561-L572).

Comment: Thanks mate, but the save path, don't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Strange, because the source file is giving you the error when `file_exists` is false, so what is the value of the variable ?

Comment: Well thats just it. The path is just 'example.pdf'.

Comment: have you installed puppeteer? if not then install it using `npm install puppeteer` and check the requirements for [Browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot#requirements).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in a PHP project. Installing the puppeteer package worked for me.

`npm install puppeteer`

Comment: This worked for me on windows. However, I initially installed it with ```npm install -g puppeteer``` and it did not work that way.

Comment: i did this. but still not working

Answer (score 3):

I had yesterday the same problem. I have now solved it by using a specific version of puppeteer and that works.

```
npm install puppeteer@^14.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the latest node version.

Comment: from node version 14 to latest ( i have tried ). it didn't work for me